# How to let status bar not to be pulled in my activity?

Tags: android

I want to let status bar visible but can not be pulled in my activity, is it possible?

If use `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

the status bar is invisible.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli Yes, I want the status bar to be visible but can not be pulled down.

Comment: Why developer's comes up with these kind of requirements that affects user's interaction with phone. After all, it is their phone and let them use it the way they want..

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

I've been there before - you think you have an interaction that requires overriding some default system behavior (back button, home button, etc).

User expect those buttons (and the status bar) to behave in a certain way and will get annoyed if you override it.

Comment: I am writing an application which is like the LockScreen, I want to make its UI same as LockScreen's.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us why would you want to block StatusBar from being pulled?
As rightly pointed out by [theelfismike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337412/theelfismike), this isn't a best practice to follow.

I suspect you are trying to achieve something which can be gracefully done otherwise.

Comment: I am writing an application which is like the LockScreen, I want to make its UI same as LockScreen's.